# nested expandable items in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a recycler view that has 2 section headers and these headers can contain normal items as well as expandable headers to display more of the standard item. See image.

Looking for some recommendations as to how to implement this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Expandable RecyclerView](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) for your purpose.

Basically you'll create two `ViewHolder`s:

1. `GroupViewHolder` for tier 1 elements
2. `ChildViewHolder` for tier 2 elements

Then just extend `ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter` to populate your data into the viewholders. Check the [README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/README.md) for exact details.

You can also checkout [Groupie](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie) but that library provides way more functionality than what you need

Comment: So am i able to have main section headers that are non expandable for the ins and outs (in image) as well as non expandable items with this library? i think image shows better what i want to do. Thanks

Comment: Try to make the non expanding headers have 0 children. I think that should work

Comment: @the_enslayer added one more suggestion in the answer